# How to specific a key in application.propertes when deploy two spring boot wars in one tomcat container

Tags: spring-boot

I came across a problem when use spring boot framework,i use one spring boot code base and package two wars.

When I deploy two wars into a tomcat container,I found two wars has the same application.properties,but I need set different values for some keys in application.properties.

How can I set this key?

Comment: What is your build tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sanjay's answer is good if you are not changing file structure much. If you need to differenciate files also, you can do something similar to below method.

If you are using `gradle`,

```
if (project.hasProperty('war1')) {
     apply from: 'war1.gradle'
} else if (project.hasProperty('war2')) {
     apply from: 'war2.gradle'
}
```

You can specify any build property in specific build file and override any task in that file. Good example found [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gradle).

You can run this as

```
./gradlew bootRun -Pwar1
```

You can do the same thing using maven.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `#{servletContext.contextPath}` in your *application.properties*. For example, you can do something like

```
spring.proiles.active=#{servletContext.contextPath}
```

Then, having [different property files](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) like

```
application-context1.properties
application-context2.properties
```

should work.

Comment: seems it does not work.i don't find any document for set spring.proiles.active=#{servletContext.contextPath}